# Must the SD of a 'bell shaped' distribution be less than the SD of a skewed distribution with the same range?

Tags: self-study, standard-deviation

> 10) Which of the following distributions will have the smallest
>   standard deviation, assuming that none contain outliers?
>   a) A uniform distribution of integers with a mean of 5 and a range of 10.
>   b) A bell-shaped distribution of integers with a mean of 5 and a range of 10.
>   c) A right-skewed distribution of integers with a mean of 4 and a range of 10.
>   d) All three distributions have equal standard deviation.
>   e) The answer cannot be determined from the information given.

The answer is given as (b) but I really can't figure out a simple reason why.

Comment: Can you think of a reason why d) is not true?

Comment: A very poorly worded question. b) and c) are quite vague. The answer is actually e, I think. Although what b) is is not that clear.

Comment: What are your guesses to why? What have you done for work on this besides just ask this list? Try making up some numbers from hypothetical distributions with these properties and see what you find in terms of SD.

Comment: @John +1 given the OP has already been given what's essentially a wrong answer, you should feel free, if you wish, to explain the issue in a detailed answer.

Comment: I just felt a homework question should show a little more work before answering. Yours is a fine answer as to why (b) is certainly not correct given the information in the question. You can exclude (a) and (d) but (e) is the most correct as it stands.

Comment: What about Binomial[10,p] distributions with p = .5 and .4 ?

Comment: @John Normally I'd strongly agree with you on the homework aspect (for several reasons), but in this case I think the fact that the OP has been given an incorrect answer puts more of an onus on us to clearly contradict the incorrect information.

Answer (score 11):

While you should be able to argue that the sd of (b) should be less than that of (a), you can't coherently argue, based on the given information, that it will be less than that of (c); it may be, but it also may not.

Here's an example which should suggest to you that the answer should not be the general statement implied by choosing (b). Here are histograms of samples, one skewed, and one more bell-shaped:

[image: Bell vs skew]

They have the right mean and range (answers calculated in R):

```
> mean(xb);mean(xc)
[1] 5
[1] 4
> diff(range(xb));diff(range(xc))
[1] 10
[1] 10
```

Yet the standard deviation of the skewed one is smaller:

```
> sd(xb);sd(xc)
[1] 2.100015
[1] 1.853432
```

Here I generate a bell-shaped distribution that looks much more normal (rather than just generically bell-shaped) than that red one above, still with the same outcome. Here the light grey bars are the normal-looking sample while the red-bordered bars are the skew sample:

[image: skew vs norm, 2nd example]

```
> max(xb2)-min(xb2);mean(xb2);sd(xb2)  # the normal-looking data
[1] 10
[1] 5
[1] 1.51216
> max(xc2)-min(xc2);mean(xc2);sd(xc2)  # the skewed data
[1] 10
[1] 4
[1] 1.499837
```

(Indeed, the standard deviation of a skewed sample could be made *much* smaller than that of a bell-shaped sample, but it suffices to produce one where it's smaller at all)

Such examples eliminate (b) and (d) as answers. Similarly, it's easy to construct examples where (c) is contradicted. (Similar examples may be also be constructed with continuous distributions rather than samples; indeed my examples began by drawing samples from distributions with the desired properties and then tweaking the resulting samples a little to produce sample results with those properties.)

Since we can produce examples that contradict answers (a) to (d), we're left with (e) as the only plausible answer.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that standard deviation is all about average distance from the mean. That the distribution is bell shaped means that moving away from the mean in either direction decreases the likelihood of new observations. With a strong right skew, you could move away from the mean into a higher likelihood region, which would lead to higher average deviations from the mean in typical situations.

But I think you could argue (e), especially if you are able to find a concrete counterexample.